# Our training/validation loss curves are great but the testing performance suffers

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

We are currently working on an image classification task for detecting tuberculosis from chest x-ray images. You can see our code below. We used 0.7 for the train set, 0.2 for the validation set, and 0.1 for the test set. Our training and validation loss is here

[image: validation loss]

But when we try it on our test data set, this is what we got:

[image: classification report]

Is there something wrong with our code? Thank you in advance.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from datetime import datetime, date
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import numpy as np

#Loading a pre-trained model
image_size = 224

base_model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))

loss_func = BinaryCrossentropy()
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

model.compile(loss=loss_func,
              optimizer=opt,  
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#Training
test_path = '...' 
val_path = '...'

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,horizontal_flip = True, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range=0.2)

batch_size=32
validation_size=8

train_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path, 
                                        target_size = (image_size, image_size),
                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(val_path, 
                                             target_size = (image_size, image_size),
                                             batch_size=validation_size,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

#Fitting the data to the model
model_name = 'MobileNetV2'
date_today= date.today().strftime('%m_%d_%Y')

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=f'Models/{model_name}_{date_today}.h5',
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             mode='min',
                             verbose=1, 
                             save_best_only=True)

model_history = model.fit(train_set, 
                          validation_data=validation_set,
                          epochs=100,
                          steps_per_epoch=len(train_set)//batch_size,
                          validation_steps=len(validation_set)//validation_size,
                          callbacks=[checkpoint],
                          verbose=1)


#Testing the model on the test set
test_path = '...'

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                            target_size = (image_size, image_size),
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

predictions = model.predict(test_set, verbose=1)

y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
class_labels = list(test_set.class_indices.keys())  

print('Classification Report')
clsf = classification_report(test_set.classes, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(clsf)
print('\n')
print('Confusion Matrix')
cfm = confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred)
print(cfm)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct but, there is one little mistake I found and that is you have assigned 2 units in `sigmoid` output layer. That's not correct; there should be 1 unit because it's a binary classification problem. Like this:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuberculosis is a complex object with sophisticated features. Therefore, the testing set may produce unexpected results. To circumvent this, you must modify your network and incorporate additional training images. You can experiment with transfer learning, but if the network from which you want to transfer the parameters was trained on objects entirely unrelated to tuberculosis, it might not be appropriate.